# Noncommutative algebraic operation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Can we always find a non-commutative algebraic operation in a non-empty set?

Comment: By algebraic operation, do you mean that it might not be associative?

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you mean? If you are looking at a binary operation $S\times S \to S$ then you don't have much option for a set of size $1$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

composition is a non-commutative binary operation on the set of bijections with domain and codomain $A$ whenever $|A|>2$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the answer is yes - given any set $X$ with more than one element, let $*$ be left projection: $x*y=x$.

---

If we ask for a noncommutative operation *satisfying some other restrictions*, of course, then the answer can be quite surprising. My favorite example: there are **no** noncommutative division rings of finite cardinality! That is, given any finite abelian group $(G, +)$, there is no binary operation $*$ on $G$ such that $(G, *)$ is a division ring and $*$ is noncommutative. This is [Wedderburn's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn's_little_theorem); I'm *still* shocked by this result.

Comment: Note that this operation is associative.

Answer (score 0):

If the set has just one element, there's only one binary operation, which is obviously commutative.

If the set has at least two elements, let $x$ and $y$ be distinct elements and define
$$
x\cdot y=x,\quad y\cdot x=y,
$$
and $z\cdot x=x\cdot z=z\cdot y=y\cdot z=x$ for all other elements $z$